# Authlogic admin subsite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, admin

Following this [tutorial](http://www.travisdunn.com/secure-rails-admin-backend-with-authlogic-and-multiple-sessions/comment-page-1#comment-7432) getting the following errors:

```
 NameError in Admin/dashboardsController#show

uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardsController



 NameError in Admin sessionController#new

uninitialized constant Admin::AdminHelper
```

not sure how to correct this!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the follwing correct

1. **Admin::WhateverController** is under **RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/admin/** directory.
2. **Admin::WhateverHelper** is under **RAILS_ROOT/app/helpers/admin/** directory
3. **Admin::WhateverController** should be named as **dashboards_controller.rb**
4. **Admin::WhateverHelper** should be named as **dashboards_helper.rb**